# List comprehension of an array that I created using np.loadtxt

Tags: python

I need to do list comprehension of an array that I created:

```
array([['12/12/80', '0.513393'],
       ['12/15/80', '0.486607'],
       ['12/16/80', '0.450893'],
       ...,
       ['2/20/19', '172.029999'],
       ['2/21/19', '171.059998'],
       ['2/22/19', '172.970001']], dtype='<U10')
```

The output should look like this:

```
array([[datetime.datetime(1980, 12, 12, 0, 0), 0.513393],
       [datetime.datetime(1980, 12, 15, 0, 0), 0.486607],
       [datetime.datetime(1980, 12, 16, 0, 0), 0.450893],
       [datetime.datetime(1980, 12, 17, 0, 0), 0.462054],
       [datetime.datetime(1980, 12, 18, 0, 0), 0.475446]], dtype=object)
```

I am struggling for the right code to do the list comprehension. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
[[datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, '%m/%d/%y'), float(val)] for dt, val in arr]
```